# Create dynamic instance of Image from the library

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I simply want to build a slide show from 80 images in my library.
So my problem is to create instance of each image(mc) from the library to the stage using a loop

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

You could place them all on stage (without any instances names or linkage) into a new movieclip (lets call that one *mcHolder* for instance), and them access them like this:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < mcHolder.numChildren; i++)
{
   var photo:DisplayObject = mcHolder.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObject;

   // Do something with the photos, like place them random on the screen.
   photo.x = Math.random() * 400;
   photo.y = Math.random() * 400;
   photo.rotation = -10 + Math.random() * 20;
}
```

Hope that helps!